# Изменение указателя внутри функции (языке C)

Tags: c, функции, указатели

Хотел спросить про изменение указателя в функции, т. е. изменение его адреса, а не значения, на которое он указывает. У меня в функции может произойти ситуация, когда надо будет расширить указатель двумерный массив строк. Сначала я передавал в функцию обычный `char** argv`, но когда происходило расширение `argv`, то сам `argv` в `main` изменялся по другому. Я попробовал сделать в функции передачу `char*** argv`, и работать с `(*argv)`, как с `argv` в предыдущем случае и все заработало. Я наверное могу понять почему так происходит, но хотелось бы услышать более академическое обоснование этой ситуации. И так же хотел спросить, почему если я предаю в функции очищение двумерного массива `argv`, то вроде все работает, код функции очищения:

```
void freeArgv(char** argv, const size_t argc) {
    if (argv == NULL) {
        return;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        if (argv[i] != NULL) {
            free(argv[i]);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    free(argv);
}
```

Comment: Если вы говорите о том `argv[]`,  что передается в `main()`, то **по крайней мере в линуксе** его элементы содержат адреса в стеке и не стоит передавать их в функцию `free()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы вы ни передавали в функцию по значению (а в C *все передается по значению*; называть передачу указателя по значению передачей по указателю - просто затуманивание мозгов в плохих учебниках...) - это создает лишь **копию**, которая является локальной переменной функции.

Когда вы передаете в функцию указатель - создается его копия. Поэтому пока вы изменяете то, на что она указывает - эти изменения остаются в указанной памяти. Но когда вы изменяете сам переданный указатель - то вы изменяете локальную переменную, которая по завершении функции исчезает.

Вас же не удивляет, что в функции

```
void f() { void * p; /* работа с p */ }
```

переменная `p` исчезает, никак не влияя на переменные вне функции?

Но здесь

```
void f(void * p) { /* работа с p */ }
```

`p` - точно такая же локальная переменная, только инициализированная передаваемым в функцию значением параметра.

Так более-менее понятно?

В вашей функции освобождения все работает, потому что все, что нужно - это значения указателей, а не сами переменные.

Проверьте сами - после

```
char ** argv; 
...
freeArgv(argv,argc);
```

значение `argv` останется прежним. Но указывать оно теперь будет на освобожденную память.